# Angular: checkbox value is not binded in ngModel

Tags: angular

I have a list of checkbox values, when I select all the checkboxes on first time, it's saved and it's displaying as expected. (All the checkboxes are checked.) When I try to update the checkbox by uncheck a box, the data is saved in table, also I am able to print the value in the console.

But unable to bind the values in UI.

Got the error: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'

```
<tr *ngFor="let object of myEntity.myList">
    <td>{{object.stringValue }}</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="myList" formControlName="myList" value={{object.checked}} [(ngModel)]="object.checkBox" />

    </td>
    <td>
        {{object.checked}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Why dont you just use `<input type="checkbox" name="myList" formControlName="myList" [(ngModel)]="object.checkBox" />`. Remove the Value attribute.

Comment: because you bind it with object.checkBox and in UI you render object.checked which is not the same

Comment: You're mixing reactive forms and template-driven forms directives here. If you have ngModel, you should have name, and no formControlName, and no value. If you have formControlName, you should have no name, no ngModel, and no value. I suggest you read up more on forms.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have removed value attribute, even though it's not working. for single check box it's working but not for array of check box.